# Swift MacOS know the version of the OS and Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I should print for a program on macOS, the Xcode and OS version.

Eg:

```
OS: macOS 12.3
Xcode: 13.3
```

How can I do?

Edit:

Maybe for the mac version I did it:

```swift
let osVersion = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.clearContents()
pasteboard.setString("MacOS: 
\(osVersion.majorVersion).
\(osVersion.minorVersion).
\(osVersion.patchVersion)", forType: .string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the macOS version, you can indeed get it from [`ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1410906-operatingsystemversion).

For the Xcode version, you can first find where Xcode's bundle is from its bundle ID, find its bundle, and get the version from its bundle's Info.plist as a string.

```
guard let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.dt.Xcode"),
      let bundle = Bundle(url: url) else {
    print("Xcode is not installed")
    exit(1)
}

guard let infoDict = bundle.infoDictionary,
      let version = infoDict["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String else {
    print("No version found in Info.plist")
    exit(1)
}
print(version) // Example output: 13.1
```

You can replace the `let url = ...` step with a `NSOpenPanel` prompt to let the user choose where their Xcode is installed too.

Comment: Because if XCode is installed in a different place, what does it return?

Comment: @Paul If you use its bundle ID, it doesn't matter if it is installed in a different place. :)

Comment: being that you said: You can replace the let url = ... step with a NSOpenPanel prompt to let the user choose where their Xcode is installed too.

Comment: I would need to find a solution that handles all the options.

Comment: I say that because `urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier:)` is sort of a black box as far as I know. I'm just suggesting that asking for the user is a more reliable option. @Paul

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to do if it is not found, asked where it is?

Comment: @Paul Yeah, I don't see why you can't do that. You'll just declare a `let xcodeUrl: URL` and then use an if statement to assign to it `if let url = NSWorkspace... { xcodeUrl = url } else { xcodeUrl = /* show NSOpenPanel here */ }`

Comment: If you have time or when you have it, I can ask you if you can update your answer by adding this possible case as well. ;)